# weight() in SELECT seems not allowed on distributed index

Tags: search, indexing, sphinx, ranking

I am using Sphinx 2.1.4-release (rel21-r4421) on an index distributed over two machines. I want to rerank the results to be a mix between the weight() returned by the Sphinx ranker, as well as my own score that's included in a field. The query looks like the following:

```
SELECT id, name, weight()+score as rank FROM data WHERE match('test') ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10;
```

According to the docs, this should be a valid query. And it does work on a single index. However, when I query a distributed index composed of two shards, only one returns a result set and from the other I get a warning:

**index data: agent 127.0.0.1:9312: remote error: select: syntax error, unexpected SEL_WEIGHT near 'weight()+score as rank'**

The configuration is set as follows:

```
index data
{
    type = distributed
    local = data_0
    agent = 127.0.0.1:9312:data_1
}
```

If I move both shards to the local server and change the configuration to this:

```
index data
{
    type = distributed
    local = data_0
    local = data_1
}
```

Everything works as it should and I get results from both shards.

This seems like a bug to me, or might it be a configuration issue?

Comment: are both machines, definitly using the same version of sphinx?

Comment: Yes, both are running Sphinx 2.1.4-release (rel21-r4421)

Comment: Then can only suggest reporting a bug sphinxsearch.com/bugs/